# The console log keeps giving me an error, how do i fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I use replit but the console log keeps telling me that a script is missing everytime i try to run it
since i use replit but in the replit file it says `run = "npm start"` and everytime i run that it says the script "start" is missing
[here you can see the pic where it gives the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiY8U.png)

Comment: You have to define the `start` command in package.json

Answer (score 2):

You should edit your package.json file and add the following:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    }
}
```

(only add the scripts, don't remove the current content of the file)